# Adding multiple images to a word document at a specific locations OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I am using Office Open XML and I have to add images at a specific points. On the document I have a 'tag' so I can locate it just fine. However, when I add more than one image, it corrupts the file.

[image]

Here's my code: (Modified from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430.aspx)

Using:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;
```

My Main:

```
private const string Loc = @"D:\Documents\2-Mass Output.docx";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var images = new[]
    {
        @"D:\Documents\NPL.bmp",
        @"D:\Documents\NVT.bmp",
        @"D:\Documents\MPL.bmp",
        @"D:\Documents\MVT.bmp"
    };
    var tags = new[]
    {
        "NormalGraph1",
        "NormalGraph2",
        "MisGraph1",
        "MisGraph2"
    };

    InsertPicture(Loc, images, tags);
}
```

Here are the methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts a picture in a paragraph with a specific text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="document">Where the file is located</param>
/// <param name="fileName">Name of the image file</param>
/// <param name="tag">Insert Image in the first paragraph that contains this text</param>
public static void InsertPicture(string document, string[] fileName, string[] tag)
{
    using (var wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        var mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

        for (var i = 0; i < fileName.Length; i++)
        {
            var imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Bmp);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName[i], FileMode.Open))
            {
                imagePart.FeedData(stream);
            }
            AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), tag[i]);
        }
    }
}

private static void AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId, string tag)
{
    // Define the reference of the image.
    var element =
            new Drawing(
                new DW.Inline(
                    new DW.Extent { Cx = 5d.Inches(), Cy = 2.66.Inches() }, // Width and Height of the image in inches. 1" = 1000000L
                    new DW.EffectExtent
                    {
                        LeftEdge = 0L,
                        TopEdge = 0L,
                        RightEdge = 0L,
                        BottomEdge = 0L
                    },
                    new DW.DocProperties
                    {
                        Id = 1U,
                        Name = tag // Make sure all of the images have a different name
                    },
                    new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                        new A.GraphicFrameLocks { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                    new A.Graphic(
                        new A.GraphicData(
                            new PIC.Picture(
                                new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                    new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties
                                    {
                                        Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                        Name = $"{tag}.bmp" // Make sure all of the images have a different name
                                    },
                                    new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                new PIC.BlipFill(
                                    new A.Blip(
                                        new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                            new A.BlipExtension
                                            {
                                                Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                            })
                                    )
                                    {
                                        Embed = relationshipId,
                                        CompressionState = A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                    },
                                    new A.Stretch(
                                        new A.FillRectangle())),
                                new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                    new A.Transform2D(
                                        new A.Offset { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                        new A.Extents { Cx = 5d.Inches(), Cy = 2.66.Inches() }), // Width and Height of the image in inches. 1" = 1000000L
                                    new A.PresetGeometry(
                                        new A.AdjustValueList()
                                    )
                                    { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                        )
                        { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                )
                {
                    DistanceFromTop = 0U,
                    DistanceFromBottom = 0U,
                    DistanceFromLeft = 0U,
                    DistanceFromRight = 0U,
                    EditId = "50D07946"
                });

    // Append the reference to the specific paragraph that contains the 'tag'.
    wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.InnerText.Contains(tag))?.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
}
```

Function for converting an inch into an inch according to Word:

```
private static long Inches(this double size)
{
    return (long) (size*1000000);
}
```

**EDIT:** Here are the contents of the header1.xml. They are the same before and after adding the images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:hdr xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14"><w:p w:rsidR="007D4EA8" w:rsidRPr="00E6041C" w:rsidRDefault="00292B4C" w:rsidP="00292B4C"><w:pPr><w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="24"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00E6041C"><w:rPr><w:noProof/><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:drawing><wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251658240" behindDoc="1" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="2F59D91E" wp14:editId="24EB15EA"><wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/><wp:positionH relativeFrom="page"><wp:align>right</wp:align></wp:positionH><wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph"><wp:posOffset>-157972</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV><wp:extent cx="7792085" cy="661254"/><wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="5715"/><wp:wrapNone/><wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/></wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:nvPicPr><pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Picture 1" descr="T:\Reich USA Commercial\Logo\Logos - US\Reich USA Letterhead.png"/><pic:cNvPicPr><a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1"/></pic:cNvPicPr></pic:nvPicPr><pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="rId1" cstate="print"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"><a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:blip><a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch></pic:blipFill><pic:spPr bwMode="auto"><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="7792085" cy="661254"/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom><a:noFill/><a:ln><a:noFill/></a:ln><a:effectLst/><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{53640926-AAD7-44D8-BBD7-CCE9431645EC}"><a14:shadowObscured xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main"/></a:ext></a:extLst></pic:spPr></pic:pic></a:graphicData></a:graphic><wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="margin"><wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth></wp14:sizeRelH><wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="margin"><wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight></wp14:sizeRelV></wp:anchor></w:drawing></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00E6041C"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>TV</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="007843C2"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>A</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00E6041C"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> Number: </w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>&lt;</w:t></w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>TVCNum</w:t></w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>&gt;</w:t></w:r>
</w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00940058" w:rsidRDefault="00940058"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Header"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00BB3259" w:rsidRPr="00940058" w:rsidRDefault="00292B4C"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Header"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00926942"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">Torsional Vibration </w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="007843C2"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t>Analysis</w:t></w:r>
</w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00BB3259" w:rsidRPr="0037430D" w:rsidRDefault="00BB3259" w:rsidP="00F909DF"><w:pPr><w:tabs><w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="4680"/><w:tab w:val="right" w:pos="9360"/></w:tabs><w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00292B4C"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">Customer: </w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>&lt;Customer&gt;</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F909DF"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:tab/></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F909DF"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:tab/></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F909DF" w:rsidRPr="0037430D"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">Performed </w:t></w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/><w:r w:rsidR="00F909DF" w:rsidRPr="0037430D"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>By</w:t></w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/><w:r w:rsidR="00F909DF" w:rsidRPr="0037430D"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">: </w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>&lt;User&gt;</w:t></w:r>
</w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00AF585E" w:rsidRPr="00BB3259" w:rsidRDefault="00645FF6" w:rsidP="00F909DF"><w:pPr><w:tabs><w:tab w:val="right" w:pos="9360"/></w:tabs><w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:noProof/><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><mc:AlternateContent><mc:Choice Requires="wps"><w:drawing><wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251660288" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="26F2E2C8" wp14:editId="4EF2E467"><wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/><wp:positionH relativeFrom="page"><wp:posOffset>-74874</wp:posOffset></wp:positionH><wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph"><wp:posOffset>173822</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV><wp:extent cx="7950241" cy="0"/><wp:effectExtent l="38100" t="19050" r="69850" b="114300"/><wp:wrapNone/><wp:docPr id="3" name="Straight Connector 3"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/><a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"><wps:wsp><wps:cNvCnPr/><wps:spPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="7950241" cy="0"/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="line"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom><a:ln w="12700"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="335BA3"/></a:solidFill></a:ln><a:effectLst><a:outerShdw blurRad="50800" dist="38100" dir="5400000" algn="t" rotWithShape="0"><a:prstClr val="black"><a:alpha val="40000"/></a:prstClr></a:outerShdw></a:effectLst></wps:spPr><wps:style><a:lnRef idx="3"><a:schemeClr val="accent5"/></a:lnRef><a:fillRef idx="0"><a:schemeClr val="accent5"/></a:fillRef><a:effectRef idx="2"><a:schemeClr val="accent5"/></a:effectRef><a:fontRef idx="minor"><a:schemeClr val="tx1"/></a:fontRef></wps:style><wps:bodyPr/></wps:wsp></a:graphicData></a:graphic><wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="margin"><wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth></wp14:sizeRelH><wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="margin"><wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight></wp14:sizeRelV></wp:anchor></w:drawing></mc:Choice><mc:Fallback><w:pict><v:line w14:anchorId="04485610" id="Straight Connector 3" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" style="position:absolute;z-index:251660288;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:page;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin" from="-5.9pt,13.7pt" to="620.1pt,13.7pt" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#xA;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#xA;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#xA;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#xA;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#xA;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#xA;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#xA;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#xA;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#xA;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#xA;IQBbmIBsOAIAAMIEAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysVE2P0zAQvSPxHyzfadJmy5ao6Qq6Wi4I&#xA;qi2Is+vYiYVjW2O3af89YyebrRYEEqIH12PPx3tvxlnfnTtNTgK8sqai81lOiTDc1so0Ff329eHN&#xA;ihIfmKmZtkZU9CI8vdu8frXuXSkWtrW6FkAwifFl7yrahuDKLPO8FR3zM+uEwUtpoWMBTWiyGliP&#xA;2TudLfL8bdZbqB1YLrzH0/vhkm5SfikFD1+k9CIQXVHEFtIKaT3ENdusWdkAc63iIwz2Dyg6pgwW&#xA;nVLds8DIEdQvqTrFwXorw4zbLrNSKi4SB2Qzz1+w2bfMicQFxfFuksn/v7T882kHRNUVLSgxrMMW&#xA;7QMw1bSBbK0xKKAFUkSdeudLdN+aHYyWdzuIpM8SuviPdMg5aXuZtBXnQDge3r5b5oubOSX86S57&#xA;DnTgw0dhOxI3FdXKRNqsZKdPPmAxdH1yicfakB6HbXGb58nNW63qB6V1vPTQHLYayIlhy4ti+eF9&#xA;Qo8prtzQ0iZ6izQjWCUa9hgE7Nu6Jwd9hEeGqizzFRYhtYq4itV8MHCAljd5/FHCdIOTHygBG76r&#xA;0KamRfoxY0Q9gTloxn8MvLRr2YAwpYnyjhzRO+0nLMm6gpnFPgzKp124aBFLafMoJHYStS4GVeIb&#xA;ElN1xrkwYTmWSt4xTKJsU+Ao558CR/8YOoCaghd/rzpFpMrWhCm4U8bC7xKE83yELAd/1OOKd9we&#xA;bH1JM5ku8KEkycZHHV/itZ3Cnz89m58AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCYJDdN2wAAAAoBAAAP&#xA;AAAAZHJzL2Rvd25yZXYueG1sTI/BTsMwDIbvSLxDZCQuaEtbDZi6ptOEtAdgTBNHtwlttcSpkqwr&#xA;b48nDnC0/ev7P1fb2VkxmRAHTwryZQbCUOv1QJ2C48d+sQYRE5JG68ko+DYRtvX9XYWl9ld6N9Mh&#xA;dYIhFEtU0Kc0llLGtjcO49KPhvj25YPDxGPopA54ZbizssiyF+lwIG7ocTRvvWnPh4vj3vbzadw9&#xA;H9Gu96Fh3GnC3Cn1+DDvNiCSmdNfGG76rA41OzX+QjoKq2CR56yeFBSvKxC3QLHKChDN70bWlfz/&#xA;Qv0DAAD//wMAUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhALaDOJL+AAAA4QEAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFtD&#xA;b250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAOP0h/9YAAACUAQAACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;AAAvAQAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAW5iAbDgCAADCBAAADgAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;AAAuAgAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAmCQ3TdsAAAAKAQAADwAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;AAAAAACSBAAAZHJzL2Rvd25yZXYueG1sUEsFBgAAAAAEAAQA8wAAAJoFAAAAAA==&#xA;" strokecolor="#335ba3" strokeweight="1pt"><v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/><v:shadow on="t" color="black" opacity="26214f" origin=",-.5" offset="0,3pt"/><w10:wrap anchorx="page"/></v:line></w:pict></mc:Fallback></mc:AlternateContent></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="008453E8"><w:t xml:space="preserve">Customer Ref. â€“ No.  </w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00BB3259"><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0" w:rsidRPr="00BB1CB1"><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t>&lt;</w:t></w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0" w:rsidRPr="00BB1CB1"><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t>CustRef</w:t></w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0" w:rsidRPr="00BB1CB1"><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t>&gt;</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F909DF"><w:tab/></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00DE1633"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t>Mahwah</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="0029773E"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t>,</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00DE1633"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> NJ</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00EE3F20" w:rsidRPr="00EE3F20"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="0029773E"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t>-</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00EE3F20" w:rsidRPr="00EE3F20"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00F972A0"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="16"/></w:rPr><w:t>&lt;Date&gt;</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="0037430D" w:rsidRPr="00EE3F20"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:sz w:val="10"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r>
</w:p></w:hdr>
```

Comment: Is the above code everything that you are running? Using the same code I cannot reproduce the error. The error message also suggests an issue with the Header XML but your code only touches the main body of the document.

Comment: Right, that's the confusing part, that's all of my code.

Comment: Are you able to list the contents of the header1.xml file?

Comment: I ran a file comparison to header1.xml for both and `The two files are identical`, I'll add it to the question anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see 3 issues with the code you've posted but I'm not sure why you would only see an error if you output more than one image.

The first issue is the `Id` of the `DocProperties`. The `Id` property should be unique amongst all of the `DocProperties` in the document.

```
new DW.DocProperties
{
    Id = 1U, //this should be unique amongst ALL DocProperties within the document
    Name = tag // Make sure all of the images have a different name
},
```

The second issue is very similar; the `Id` of each of the `NonVisualDrawingProperties` should also be unique across each `NonVisualDrawingProperties` instance.

Note that in both cases you will need these values to be unique from the values that already exist in your header. From the header XML that you posted you can see that you already have instances of those properties:

```
<wp:docPr id="1" name="NormalGraph2" />
```

and

```
<pic:cNvPr id="0" name="NormalGraph2.bmp" />
```

Finally, the third issue I can see is in the code where you add the `element`. In that code you are finding the `Paragraph` that contains the `tag` and then appending a `Paragraph` to the existing `Paragraph`. A `Paragraph` is not allowed to be a child of another `Paragraph`. Instead, you should just add the `Run` to the existing `Paragraph` like so:

```
wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.InnerText.Contains(tag))?.AppendChild(new Run(element));
```

or, if you need the separate paragraphs then add the `Paragraph` after the tag `Paragraph` against the same `Parent` node:

```
var tagNode = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.InnerText.Contains(tag));
if (tagNode != null)
{
    tagNode.Parent.InsertAfter(new Run(element), tagNode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the ID being identical. Which is odd because that's what I thought it was last time. That resolved my issue. I just passed in `i` as an index and gave them ids as `(uint)(index + 4)`.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help @Blue Eyed Behemoth

Comment: I just changed the `id` of the `<wp:docPr id="1">` part and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: I was using a template document that already consisted of some images. Therefore some id where the same and it gave problems. So when adding images now, I added 100 to the ID counter and now everything is fine, thanks for this post, it took me a lot of time and tears to find this solution!

Comment: Mine was also coming from id. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution based on the advice in this thread!
The first method gives me the reference id. This id can be reused if I want to add the image more times, but every image insertion should get a unique ID:

```
AddImageToBody(_imgKReferenceID, $"imgOK{creditNr}", 60, 60, (UInt32)(counter + 100)

public static string InsertAPicture(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }
        return mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log.Error(ex);
        return "";
    }

}

internal static Drawing AddImageToBody(string relationshipId, string name , int w = 60, int h = 60, UInt32 id1=1U, UInt32 id2 = 0U)
{
    System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(w, h);

    Int64Value width = size.Width/2 * 9525;
    Int64Value height = size.Height/2 * 9525;

    var draw = new Drawing(
        new DW.Inline(
            new DW.Extent() { Cx = width, Cy = height },
            new DW.EffectExtent()
            {
                LeftEdge = 0L,
                TopEdge = 0L,
                RightEdge = 0L,
                BottomEdge = 0L
            },
            new DW.DocProperties()
            {
                Id = (UInt32Value)id1,
                Name = $"{name}"
            },
            new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
            new A.Graphic(
                new A.GraphicData(
                    new PIC.Picture(
                        new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                            new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                            {
                                Id = (UInt32Value)id2,
                                Name = $"{name}"
                            },
                            new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                            new PIC.BlipFill(
                                new A.Blip(
                                    new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                        new A.BlipExtension() { Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" })
                                    )
                                {
                                    Embed = relationshipId,
                                    CompressionState =
                                    A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                },
                                    new A.Stretch(
                                        new A.FillRectangle())),
                                        new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                            new A.Transform2D(
                                                new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                                new A.Extents() { Cx = width, Cy = height }),
                                                new A.PresetGeometry(new A.AdjustValueList()) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle })))
                { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                                                )
        {
            DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
            EditId = "50D07946"
        });

    return draw;

}
```